# Geometry shader is passing for without in layout

Tags: opengl

Here is my geometry shader without input layout

```
 #version 150
 layout( points, max_vertices = 1 ) out;
 void main()
 {
     for( int i = 0; i < gl_in.length(); i++ )
     {
         vec4 vert = gl_in[ i ].gl_Position;
         gl_Position = vert;
         gl_PointSize = gl_in[ i ].gl_PointSize;
         EmitVertex();
     }  
 }
```

This shader is compiling successfully. As far as know, It should fail as no input is given

Comment: Does it *link* successfully?

Comment: Yeah it is linking also

Comment: Well, it sounds like a driver bug then.